# QLabel show command opens new Window

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've created an Application which derives from QWidget. When I create an **QLabel** and yield the show command, it opens in a separate window. I was deriving my BaseClass from QMainWindow before which worked fine.

[image: screenshot]

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    testlabel = new my_qlabel(parent);

    QImage myImage = QImage(QString::fromStdString("D:/Lighthouse.jpg"));
    testlabel->setParent(parent);
    testlabel->name="testName";
    testlabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage, Qt::AutoColor));
    testlabel->setGeometry(QRect(500, 500, 100, 100));
    testlabel->show();
    std::cout<<"i am in the output "<<std::endl;
    qDebug() << QString("init");
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
testlabel = new my_qlabel(parent);
```

The above should probably instead be

```
testlabel = new my_qlabel(this);
```

Also make sure that your my_qlabel constructor is passing its QWidget pointer argument up to the superclass's (QLabel?) constructor.  If you forgot to do that, then the my_qlabel object will not have a parent widget, which will cause it to show up as top-level window, which would match the behavior you are seeing.

```
testlabel->show();
```

Once you have testlabel's parenting problems fixed, this show() command should no longer be necessary (or appropriate), since any child widgets you add to your Widget object will be automatically show()'n when the Widget itself is first show()'n.  (The only time you would need to manually call show() is if you had previously called hide() or setVisible(false) on that same widget, and now you wanted to make it re-appear; or if you had added the child widget to its parent widget after the parent widget was already visible on-screen; neither is the case here)